# Mixing and matching components of jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

This may be a silly question, however does anyone know the effects of mixing Jquery Mobile components.

I ask because I have an ios app that ran on an older version of Jquery mobile, and decided to turn it into an android app. There is a bug with input boxes however on HTC, so I upgraded to a newer version of Jquery mobile. This fixed the text boxes but ruined all my styling.

So is there a way to keep the old Jquery mobile stylesheet and use a newer Jquery mobile .js file? Anyone tried this?

The exact combo I am thinking of is:

```
Cordova 2.0.0
jquery-1.8.1.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.cs
```

Comment: I think that by default you do need the same style version as the js version, but why don't you just try it? Also maybe you can put together a custom version using the [download builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/)

Comment: currentky trying it and trying to iron out the bugs.. its probably going to be more work that just re-styling it though. :p

Comment: Probably, it might also be easier to try to port back the fix for the bug on HTC devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying this and mixing the combination above, although you can play about with the code enough for it to work. It turned out to be no less work than just restyling everything. Like @Jack commented though, there is also the option of a custom build. So its all roughly about the same amount of work. I would not advising mixing and matching after trying it however.